# How to change id of div element when browser resize?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code

`<div id="123"></div>`

i want to change the id to 234 when the browser resized

`<div id="234"></div>`

I have use media query , but i think it is not possible

```
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {

    #123 {

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose for the changing the `id`? Is the only purpose so that you can apply different CSS styles? Is so, the media queries would put you on the right track.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily with javascript or jQuery.
Here a example written in JS.

```js
window.onresize = function(){
    var div = document.getElementById("aaa");
    if(div){
        div.setAttribute("id", "bbb");
    }
}
```

```css
#aaa {
    font-size: 10px;
}
#bbb {
    font-size: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div id="aaa">Resize</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what you are trying to do but this can be solved with [window.onresize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize)

You generally shouldn't be changing your element IDs around but if you want to you will need some logic in the onresize function to deduce which ID your element will have when you resize your window.

Answer (score 0):

No jQuery answer

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
   if(document.getElementById('123') != null)            
   document.getElementById('123').id = '234';
};
```

Just be careful id `234` is not assigned to another element, however you should not be changing your id for changing styles as it should be done by adding and removing css classes.

Comment: You need to check whether `document.getElementById` returns anything, otherwise you'll get an error when you try to assign to `null.id`.

Comment: After it changes the ID, the next time they resize the window the old ID won't exist, so the code will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You're right! It's not possible to do with CSS, but it can be possible to do with JavaScript &/or jQuery. Try this using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com):

```
$(window).on('resize',function() {
   $('#123').attr('id','234');
});
```

The problem with the code above, is that it's a 1x only change. You could never re-target that id after the first resize. So after the browser detects that it has been resized by 2-3 pixels, then the JS will break.

The real question is, why would you want to change an id on resize? It would be better to change an HTML 5 `data-*` attribute, like: `data-id`. This allows you to be able to change it repeatedly, using the `#myUniqueId` attribute. Then your code should continue to run continuously, for as long as the window is being resized.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/779vw0ce/) for this code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="myUniqueId" data-id="123"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var id = $('#myUniqueId').attr('data-id');
    id++;
    $('#myUniqueId').attr('data-id',id);
    // Double check: what is my id? 
    var myId = $('#myUniqueId').attr('data-id');
    $('#output').html(myId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use similiar code so you can use different css for mobile or desktop... However it completely irritates me.

This way you use the same id or class. But depending on screen size it will do something different.

```
@media not all and (min-width:999px){
    /* Big Screen */
    body {background-color:green; }
    #id { background-color:red}
}

@media all and (min-width:1000px)
{
    /* Smaller Screen */
    body {background-color:blue; }
    #id { background-color:grey}
}
```

Notice how when you manually re size the screen with your mouse the color changes....to the smaller css automatically.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/  ID'S CANNOT START WITH A NUMBER.

Comment: HTML 5 removed that restriction.

Comment: Read the date on that web page: 2007.

Comment: Wow, I feel old...Thanks Barmar...LOL

Comment: I think my answer only proves that what you were doing, wasn't what you wanted to do in the first place...useful code though. :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one work for you.

```
//detect window resize
$(window).resize(function() {

    //test if window width is below 479
    $(window).width() < 479 ? small() : big();

    //small function is called when window size is smaller than 479
    function small(){
        //edited from $( "#id_changer" ).append( "<div id='123'>123</div>" );
        document.getElementByID('id_changer').innerHTML = "<div id='123'>123</div>";
    }

    //big function is called when window size is bigger than 479
    function big(){
        //edited from $( "#id_changer" ).append( "<div id='234'>234</div>" );
        document.getElementByID('id_changer').innerHTML = "<div id='234'>234</div>";
    }
});



<body>
    <div id="id_changer"></div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

Comment: This will create multiple DIVs with the same ID since it doesn't remove the old DIV before appending the new one.